# PHPMySql array insertion to table

Tags: php, mysql

I need help regarding array insertion into mysql table.

I have an array when I add and item to the shopping cart

```
$_session['cart_array'] = array("item_id" => $pid, "quantity"=>1)
```

now if I have one item in cart when I do `print_r($_session['cart_array'])` array looks like

```
Array( [0] => Array ( [item_id] => 1 [quantity] => 1 ) )
```

now I need to insert this array data to a table named purchased_products having columns

```
id, product_name, product_quantity
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$item_id = $_session['cart_array'] [item_id];
$quantity = $_session['cart_array'] [quantity];
```

Then try to insert that variable in your database:

```
$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO table_name VALUES ('NULL', '".$item_id."', '".$quantity."')");
```

Use NULL if your id is auto increment.

Hope it could help you..

Comment: thanks .it insert data but with a little problem ....

first it shows Undefined offset 1 , and 2nd prob is it inserts zero in both item_id and quantity columns every time i run it

Comment: first it shows Undefined offset 1 , and 2nd prob is it inserts zero in both item_id and quantity columns every time i run it

Comment: did you try to echo the values of your array??
maybe the structure of your table for column id is not in auto increment that's why it shows undefined offset.

Comment: yes id is auto increment and ..when i echo array using print_r is shows Array ( [0] => Array ( [item_id] => 1 [quantity] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [item_id] => 2 [quantity] => 1 ) )

in this case cart contains two items

Comment: ah..i see..
try this: 

$item_id = $_session['cart_array'] [item_id];
$quantity = $_session['cart_array'] [quantity];

Comment: I've already edited the code i post a while a go..
try it if it works

Answer (score 0):

For

```
   $_session['cart_array'] = array(array("item_id" => 1, "quantity"=>1),array("item_id" => 2, "quantity"=>2));

    foreach($_session['cart_array'] as $key=>$val){
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO (id, product_name, product_quantity) VALUES ('".$val->item_id."','NULL',  '".$val->quantity."')");

    }
```

Is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

[Serialize](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) your array with PHP function `searialize($yourarray`) and store in database.

After fetching it from database use `unserialize()` for make actual array.

More details are here :[PHP: Using serialize to handle and store arrays](https://www.namepros.com/threads/php-using-serialize-to-handle-and-store-arrays.281176/)

Comment: will the work for inserting data into table with three columns id, product_id and product_quantity .

i dont want to store array as a string in single column .as serialize does

Comment: No way to store array directly in databse. For three column you can make saperate serialized strings and store them in respective columns.

Comment: okay this is my case 

Array ( 

[0] => Array ( [item_id] => 1 [quantity] => 2 ) 
[1] => Array ( [item_id] => 4 [quantity] => 1 ) 
)

i saw the tutorial but that is not my case ...any help please

Comment: change dimensions of your array. make it like $items=array([0]=>1,[1]=>4,[2]=>3) same for quantity and others